# How do I make <Ctrl-a><Ctrl-c> copy and select all in vim?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, gvim

I know `:%y+` is a convenient way to select all and copy to the system clipboard--which works on my system--but I'm so used to using `<Ctrl-a> <Ctrl-c>` that I'd like to use the same keystroke combination in vim.

I tried adding

```
map <C-a><C-c> :%y+<CR>
```

to my .vimrc file, but it failed. ... I'm using GVim on Windows, if that matters.

Answer (score 4):

I ultimately accomplished what I wanted to do by adding:

```
map <C-a> ggVG
map <C-c> "+y
```

to my .vimrc file.

Comment: While this will work, I would highly recommend using [`noremap` instead of `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3776182/3524982). Also, `<C-a>` by default is a very useful command (increment the next number), so I would recommend mapping to something else (I have it mapped to `VV`), but of course, to each their own.

Comment: I've stolen `VV` from you.  Seems pretty intuitive!  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want the standard Windows behaviour for some keys, you can simply source the (well-known or should I rather say infamous?) [mswin.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/mswin.vim).

So simply do in your .vimrc `:ru mswin.vim` and the file will be source (it should be living in your default $VIMRUNTIME path).

Note however, that a lot of those mappings are frowned upon by proficient Vim users.